# CSS: Center Align

Tags: css, menu, alignment

I have the following CSS Menu with `float:left;` how could I make this center.  Where do I add `margin:0 auto`?

**CSS:**

```
/* === 7. Navigation === */

#nav{
    width:100%;
    margin:30px auto;
}

.ie7 #nav{
    padding:10px 0 0 30px;
}

#nav ul li{
    margin:0 auto;
}

#nav li{
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#nav li a{
    margin-right:30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#5d5e5d;
}

#nav li a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;

}

#nav li a:active{
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <ul id="nav"><!--Navigation-->
                    <li id="homenav"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li id="portfolionav"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li id="contactnav"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't have an specified width to center your menu you can just declare your list items as `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` and jut set the `text-align` property to center, like so:

**CSS**

```
#nav > li {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#nav {
    text-align:center;
}
```

This way your menu will center regardless of a width.

Answer (score 3):

Add display property of your #nav as table and margin for both left and right auto.

```
#nav{
    display:table;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
 }
```

Comment: `display: table;` will fail in older versions of IE.  And `margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;` is not much different than OP's shorthand `margin: 30px auto;`

Answer (score 1):

First your #nav element needs to have a width less than 100%. Then add "margin:0 auto" and it should center.

Comment: The #nav element actually needs a fixed-width in order for this to work.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. Change the width:100% to something like width:500px or whatever works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `#nav {...};`. Be aware that your nav needs a fixed-width in order for this to work.